# How can I apply forward fill to a groupby dynamic method in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I'm struggling with figuring out how to apply forward fill to groupby_dynamic in polars. I'm currently using it for downsampling.

```
    data_rs = (df.groupby_dynamic(index_column="Open time", every=timeframe, closed="both")
        .agg([ 
            pl.col("Price").first().alias("Open"), 
            pl.col("Price").max().alias("High"), 
            pl.col("Price").min().alias("Low"), 
            pl.col("Price").last().alias("Close")
            ])
        )
```

I noticed that when I run the code above and compare it to pandas for individual rows. Rows without data would normally be filled in pandas to match previous roll if using ffill().  In polars it's removed instead all together. I verified this when I compare the index values when downsampling in pandas with the values from polars. It seems to happen only when the previous row and the row removed would be equal due to using forward fill. What's the recommended best practice to do this in Polars with downsampling and using forward fill or backward fill?

[Example image shows 2023-03-03 16:49:30 is missing. The value for that row should be the same as 16:49:15 if forward fill is applied.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp7OK.png)

I tried applying the following to each individual column and the entire dataframe and it all failed.

```
fill_nan()
fill_null()
forward_fill()
```

```
### Code example for pl
import polars as pl

def resampling_pl(df: pl.DataFrame, timeframe: int) -> pl.DataFrame:
    df = df.with_column(pl.col("Date") + " " + pl.col("Time"))
    df = df.with_column(
        pl.col("Date").
            str.strptime(
                pl.Datetime, 
                fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%.f", 
                strict=False
            )
        .alias("Open time")
    )

    df = df.select(["Open time", "Price"])
    
    data_rs = (df.groupby_dynamic(
        index_column="Open time", every=str(timeframe)+"s", closed="both")
            .agg(
                 [
                    pl.col("Price").first().alias("Open"),
                    pl.col("Price").max().alias("High"),
                    pl.col("Price").min().alias("Low"),
                    pl.col("Price").last().alias("Close")
                ]
            )
        )

    return data_rs

### This method creates the desired result I'm looking for when using pandas instead for ffill.
def ffill_(data, timeframe):
    df = data.copy()
    df.index = df["Open time"]
    df.drop(["Open time"], axis=1, inplace=True)

    start_date = df.index.min()
    end_date = df.index.max()

    new_index = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq=str(timeframe)+'S')
    df = df.reindex(new_index)
    df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
    del data

    return df


### The functions being called for desired end result
file_path = "nq.csv"
df = pl.read_csv(file_path)
data1 = resampling_pl(df, 30).to_pandas()
data1.index = data1["Open time"]
data1 = ffill_(data1, 30)
```

Comment: Hi @user3408662, can you add a minimal reproducible example to your question? 

A minimal reproducible example would be the code to create a sample dataframe : pl.DataFrame(..), and an example of the result you want (for example a table).

This will make it easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

I think I've parsed the problem.

One way to think about this problem is we need to fill on a "nearest key" when there is no data for a bucket. This is exactly what [join_asof](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html) is for.

We can create a dataframe of all the buckets, including those that may be missing, by using `date_range` with expression input:

```
all_buckets = data_rs.select(
  pl.date_range(pl.col('Open time').first(), pl.col('Open time').last(), f'{timeframe}s')
)
```

Then the `join_asof` is simply applied. Buckets in `all_buckets` that are not in `data_rs` will be filled on nearest key, in this case the default strategy of `backward` corresponds to what is desired in the question:

`final_df = all_buckets.join_asof(data_rs, on='Open time')`

Note that all of this can be done lazily too!